# How do you add join a table using Criteria class?

Tags: criteria, hibernate-criteria

```
I am new to using Criteria, and i am trying to join tables on my query.
This is my expected query set up

Select * FROM ATable a INNER JOIN BTable b ON a.id = b.fk_id WHERE fk_pname = ":cat";
```

Do you know how i can add the "INNER JOIN BTable b ON a.id = b.fk_id"?

I already added in instance, but not sure how to add the other table.
   Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(ATable.class);

Thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do it -
Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(ATable.class)
.createAlias("btable","b")
.add(Restrictions.eq("b.pname",":cat")

The string 'btable' refers to the property name in the ATable entity class that corresponds to the BTable entity.

Comment: when you say btable refers the ATable entity, what do you mean? and how BTable entity is displayed? i guess i dont really understand the whole entity

Comment: Actually, what would i need in ATable.java file to add BTable.java to be able to refer each other?